# how to fix install gnome desktop in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos

[image]

I do like tutorial : [How to install Desktop Environments on CentOS 7?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181503/how-to-install-desktop-environments-on-centos-7), but I meet a trouble,see in this picture. How can I fix this for "startx" successed. [image]

in all install command line, i just see only this error. i try install KDE desktop too. But it still happen like that.

Comment: Please include actual text, not screenshots of text.

Comment: Did you update before trying to install Gnome/ KDE?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run:

```
yum install python-2.6
```

Maybe it will help.

Comment: There is no python-pyparsing package in my centos7/gnome installations. Moreover, the release mentioned for this package is el6.rf, which obviously is not el7 release... You need to find why this package is asked to be installed, maybe is there some active repository you should disable. Look at "yum repolist"