# how to fix error python-pyparsing when install GNOME desktop in centos 7?

Tags: centos

[image]

in first picture you see, I just type "# yum -y groups install "GNOME Desktop" 
and i meet the problem, that error, python-pyparsing, you see. How can I fix this problem? I try to do this, don't know wrong or right, i download a python 2.6 that i just found, but when install rpm, it happen like... can't understand:  pic 1, I see have python (abi) 2.7 installed, and  pic 2, it show that trouble just want to blow my mind. Can people help me how to fix this, all of that problem?  [image]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!  Please paste the commands and their output as [code blocks](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code), instead of as screenshots.  This lets others search for your question more easily, and helps screen readers.

Comment: just read it, OK. don't want too much.

Comment: @hiroshi17: You should probably be more respectful to people trying to help you.

Comment: I' sorry. But i really need help.

Comment: anyone here? I need your help,

Comment: are people hate me :(

Comment: Possibly related/duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285723/how-to-fix-install-gnome-desktop-in-centos-7

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install a version of python from CentOS6 onto a CentOS7 system.  This won't work.  You also appear to have the CentOS6 repository definition for `rpmforge`.  Not only is `rpmforge` a bad repository to use anymore (it is no longer maintained), but it's also for the wrong version of CentOS.

I suggest you figure out why you've got bad repo definitions.  I suggest reading this page for reccomended 3rd-party repos:

https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories