# Switch between Gnome and Cinnamon on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, x11, gnome3, cinnamon

I installed CentOS 7 with Gnome environment. I installed Cinnamon by following these instructions: [How to install Desktop Environments on CentOS 7?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181503/how-to-install-desktop-environments-on-centos-7)

But if I run `startx`, I see I lost my app windows and switched to Cinnamon. If I log out, I get back my Gnome GUI.

They don't say how to replace completely Gnome by Cinnamon.  (At the boot for example.)

1. When I run `startx`, it creates a new session of my user, right?
2. How to replace completely gnome by Cinnamon? Because if I need to run `startx` everytime, it will waste my resource since Gnome will be still running.

Comment: Actually you can change cinnamon as default GUI when you got login screen.You can click a login session. You can change it from login session and you can switch back to gnome too.I already tried mate and worked fine.I installed mate thru yum.

Answer (score 1):

First configure your system to start in graphical mode automatically.
startx command is something from 20 years ago.

```
systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

Now what gets you confused is most likely the login manager. The default in CentOS7 is GDM which is part of gnome. But also Cinnamon is based on gnome 3 so it uses a lot of common libraries.

In GDM you can choose to start Cinnamon when you log in also you can configure to be your default desktop environment.