# Set KDE Desktop Environment like default CentOS 7

Tags: centos, kde, desktop-environment

I want to change default Desktop environment from GNome to KDE.

My asking is for CentOS 7, I was Trying with

[How to install Desktop Environments on CentOS 7?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181503/how-to-install-desktop-environments-on-centos-7)

```
# echo "exec startkde" >> ~/.xinitrc
# startx
```

Efectively KDE Environments Starts

But, Restarting, Again I have Gnome.

I want Restarting starting with KDE.

**Where I can change deafult Desktop Environment?**

PD. Solution for CentOS 6.x doesn't work!

Answer (score 2):

In CentOS 7, there is a file `/etc/X11/xinit/Xclients` in which the default desktop will be checked. It will look for a file `/etc/sysconfig/desktop`. Therefore, we can simply create this file (`/etc/sysconfig/desktop`) and put the content `DESKTOP=KDE`. For next login, the KDE desktop environment will be used automatically.