# How to install gnome-terminal on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, gnome3, gnome-terminal

I have just installed gnome user interface on my CentOS 7 but didn't install gnome terminal. Now there isn't any other app installed than nautilus file manager and control-center. What do I do?

Comment: How did you install GNOME?

Comment: CentOS minimal installation is CLI by default. I installed gnome with the commands `# yum groupinstall "X Window System"`

`# yum install gnome-classic-session `                                `# unlink /etc/systemd/system/default.target`

`# ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/graphical.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target`

Comment: Check with this command : rpm -qa | grep gnome-terminal. You need to switch text mode and run yum install gnome-terminal.

Comment: @supriady do you mean I can switch back

Comment: you can switch graphical mode or text mode. find /etc/inittab and read it. Using systemctl to switch it.multi-user.target or graphical.target.

Answer (score 3):

If you started with the minimal installation of CentOS 7 you need to do the following to enable the Desktop:

```
$ sudo yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop" "Graphical Administration Tools"
```

Then set the default run level to 5 (X windows)

```
$ sudo ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/runlevel5.target \
   /etc/systemd/system/default.target
```

This step can be done more succinctly using systemd:

```
$ sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

Then `reboot`.

#### What if I'm locked in GNOME?

If you're somehow logged into GNOME desktop but find yourself unable to get to a `gnome-terminal` or any terminal for that matter, you can always reboot the system into runlevel 3 (multi-user with networking, no desktop).

While at the GRUB prompt, edit the kernel entry that's going to boot by hitting the letter <kbd>e</kbd>. Then go to the line that starts with the string `linux` and go to the end of this line and type the number `3`.

[image: ss1]
   [image: ss2]

**NOTE:** Then hit <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

From this point you'll be able to log into your system in console mode, run your `yum` commands to install what I mentioned above and then reboot the system.

#### References

- [Install Gnome GUI on CentOS 7 / RHEL 7](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/install-gnome-gui-on-centos-7-rhel-7.html)
- [How to install Desktop Environments on CentOS 7?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181503/how-to-install-desktop-environments-on-centos-7/264097#264097)
- [GRUB2 runlevel 3 – Howto Change runlevel on GRUB2](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/howto-change-runlevel-on-grub2/)

Comment: @QuantumK - if you're somehow stuck in X without the ability to access a terminal, reboot the system and switch to run level 3 (console) and login and do the yum installs I'm telling you in this answer, then reboot back into X and you'll have gnome-terminal.

Comment: Do you mean from grub's option menuThere's only option to boot into the OS or use a rescue version.

Comment: @QuantumK - see my updates, you can hit the e key to enter GRUBs edit menu and change the runlevel.

Comment: @QuantumK - np, the hidden menus always thwart ppl until someone else enlightens you to their existence 8-). If you're good, please mark this as accepted so other's know your issue's been resolved.