# Linux Centos does not boot on login GUI

Tags: linux, centos, gnome, login, gui

I would like to boot my Linux Centos 7 on Graphic User Interface login page but it doesn't. I have already installed GNOME DESKTOP.
I did:

```
systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

my grub file is configured like that:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap rhgb quiet rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau nouveau.modeset=0 nouveau.modeset=0 rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau plymouth.ignore-udev"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

grep EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log gives me:

```
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    82.640] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    83.213] (EE) Error loading keymap /tmp/server-0.xkm
[    83.213] (EE) XKB: Failed to load keymap. Loading default keymap instead.
```

Do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Welcome on U&L! Have you checked your logs for errors? Is the nouveau driver disabled on purpose (e.g. because you are using a proprietary Nvidia driver)?

Comment: Hello, could you tell me where can i check logs? I disabled nouveau on purposed to use NVidia drivers because since the last yum update centos was stuck on plymouth wait.

Comment: A starting point would be to query `systemd` and the journal: `systemctl --failed`, `systemctl status` for the failed units, if any; `journalctl -u graphical.target`, `journalctl -p 0..4` for log entries from priority 0 (emergency) up to 4 (warnings) (likely only about the last boot, since the journal is not persistent by default). You should also be able to look for errors in `/var/log/messages`. Please, [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/490338/edit) your question if you find something.

Comment: You can also check for the output of `systemctl isolate graphical.target` (and its messages in the journal with `journalctl`). Issued on the command line, it will start the `graphical.target` unit and its dependencies.

Comment: thanks fra-san, I gonna check all and keep you posted.

Comment: It's been a while that I last used Centos, and have never used it as a desktop environment, but does installing Gnome automatically pull in `gdm` or another login manager?

Comment: What graphics card? It almost certainly boots , my guess is you can ctrl-alt-F2 and debug the graphics

Comment: The kernel arguments lead me to think you have the 3rd party NVidia driver installed, but it’s likely that it is missing for your current kernel.  Either uninstall it or figure out why it isn’t loaded and try again?

Comment: Hello there, systemctl --failed showed me: 0 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.

Comment: journalctl -u graphical.target
-- Logs begin at ven. 2018-12-21 16:42:35 CET, end at mer. 2018-12-26 08:50:03 C
déc. 21 15:43:23 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Reached target Graphical Interface.

Comment: Your GUI not showing up is likely not related to the `Xorg` error. Rather, since `systemctl` shows no failed units, it may just depend on how you installed GNOME Desktop (as tink suggested). For instance, if you issued `yum install gnome-desktop`, you got no display manager - the component responsible to start the desktop environment. The easy way to install everything should be to run `yum -y groups install "GNOME Desktop"`. Have you come across, for instance, [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/181503/315749)?